# Android populating a listview from a listview

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

The first thing that happens once a user navigates to this page is the app populates a listview with a list of states from a remote database. Then the user selects a state and the app goes back to the database and gets a list of county's in that state. 
The states load fine, the problem is the countys don't load. In the log it shows that the page is returning an empty array. if i just go to the page http://photosbychristian.com/ems/get_countys.php?state=PA
it works fine. I'm not sure were the problem is because no errors are thrown and it worked fine the first time for getting the states.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.hospitals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Add extends ListActivity {  
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ProgressDialog cDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONParser jParserCo = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> statesList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countyList;


    // urls 
    private static String url_states = "http://photosbychristian.com/ems/get_states.php";
    String url_countys;

    // JSON Node names for states
    private static final String TAG_STATES = "states";
    private static final String TAG_TB_NAME = "tbname";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ABBR = "Abbr";

    //JSON Node names for countys
    private static final String TAG_COUNTYS = "countys";
    private static final String TAG_NAME_COUNTY = "name";



    // JSONArrays
    JSONArray states = null;
    JSONArray countys = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        //path.setText("");
        // Hashmap for ListView
        statesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        countyList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading states in Background Thread
        new LoadAllStates().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String abbr = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.abbr)).getText().toString();
                String cf = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comingFrom)).getText().toString();
                TextView path = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path); 
                Log.d("Coming From",cf);

                if (cf == "1"){//countys
                    path.append(abbr + " > ");
                    url_countys = "http://photosbychristian.com/ems/get_countys.php?state="+abbr;
                    Log.d("url", url_countys);
                    new LoadAllCountys().execute(); 

                }else if(cf == "2"){//citys
                    path.append(abbr + " > ");

                }else if (cf == "3"){//hospitals
                    path.append(abbr);


                }


            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllStates extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Add.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading states. Please wait.");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting all staets from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_states, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All States: ", json.toString());

            try {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    states = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STATES);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < states.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = states.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String table = c.getString(TAG_TB_NAME);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String abbr = c.getString(TAG_ABBR);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_TB_NAME, table);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_ABBR, abbr);
                        map.put("ComingFrom", "1");

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        statesList.add(map);
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Add.this, 
                            statesList, 
                            R.layout.hospital_items, 
                            new String[] { TAG_TB_NAME, TAG_ABBR, TAG_NAME, "ComingFrom"},  
                            new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.abbr, R.id.name, R.id.comingFrom }
                     );
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    class LoadAllCountys extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            cDialog = new ProgressDialog(Add.this);
            cDialog.setMessage("Loading countys. Please wait.");
            cDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            cDialog.setCancelable(false);
            cDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting all staets from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject jsonCo = jParserCo.makeHttpRequest(url_countys, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Countys: ", jsonCo.toString());

            try {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    countys = jsonCo.getJSONArray(TAG_COUNTYS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < countys.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = countys.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME_COUNTY);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME_COUNTY, name);
                        map.put("ComingFrom", "2");

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        countyList.add(map);
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            cDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Add.this, 
                            countyList, 
                            R.layout.hospital_items, 
                            new String[] {TAG_NAME, "ComingFrom"},  
                            new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.comingFrom }
                     );
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Also once i figure this out after the user selects a county the listview will populate with citys and then hospitals so if there is a better way to do this i'd be willing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works for me. I download the file first and then create json object using it:

```
mJsonString = downloadFileFromInternet(urls[0]);

if(mJsonString == null)
    return false;

JSONObject jObject = null;
jObject = new JSONObject(mJsonString);

----

    private String downloadFileFromInternet(String url)
        {
            if(url == null /*|| url.isEmpty() == true*/)
                new IllegalArgumentException("url is empty/null");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream inStream = null;
            try
            {
                url = urlEncode(url);
                URL link = new URL(url);
                inStream = link.openStream();
                int i;
                int total = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                while((i=inStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    if(total >= (1024 * 1024))
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                    total += i;
                    sb.append(new String(buffer,0,i));
                }
            }catch(Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String urlEncode(String url)
        {
            if(url == null /*|| url.isEmpty() == true*/)
                return null;
            url = url.replace("[","");
            url = url.replace("]","");
            url = url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
            return url;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. But still...

You can change the data set for an adapter to a listview and refresh it. This way ths list view will start to show the new set of data items.

In onItemClick of the list view, you can do something like this:

```
mAdapter.setListData(mSubMenu);

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where your mSumMenu can be county's arraylist.

Comment: The issue seems to be hapening between the http get and the json parseing